# How to create a virtual Mic on MacOS with pulseaudio

Tags: audio, virtual, core-audio, audio-streaming, microphone

I am trying to use pulseaudio with MacOS (Big sur) to create a virtual mic that can be recognised by apps systemwide.I am able to install pulseaudio without any error.
Even the following command is executing:

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MySink
```

But I am not able to see any virtual device created in my device.
What am I missing? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Where are you looking for the device? In `Audio MIDI Setup.app`?

Comment: I am opening the list of audio devices from zoom/meet . I even checked the default system wide devices by opening system preferences ->sound . But I cannot find the device anywhere.